# Cannot fetch from cursor

Tags: postgresql, datagrip

Datagrip cannot read from cursor for the below query:

```
SELECT public.get_user_summary('ALL');
FETCH ALL FROM ref1;
```

Function code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_user_summary(username text)
  RETURNS refcursor AS
$BODY$
DECLARE ref1 refcursor := 'ref1';
BEGIN
    OPEN ref1 FOR
    select * FROM public.user_details where user_name=username;
    RETURN ref1;
END
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

it works on pgAdmin but datagrip gives below error:

```
<failed to load>
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: cursor "ref1" does not exist
```

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Is Auto Commit enabled on DataGrip?

Comment: yes, Auto-commit is enabled.

Comment: Could you update your question with the code for `get_user_summary`?

Comment: updated with the function code.

Comment: SInce this is a commercial product you should ask in their support forums.

Comment: Hello! I am PMM of DataGrip from JetBrains. We know about this problem, please watch this bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-2465

Comment: Also: please turn Auto-commit off. And then there will be DataGrip problems I mentioned. As a workaround you can use something like 
BEGIN;
SELECT ReturnMultipleDataSetsForKicksAndGiggles(1,1);
FETCH ALL IN "cursor_person_info";
FETCH ALL IN "cursor_program_info";
END;

Comment: @moscas Thanks for your feedback and hope it will be fixed soon.

Comment: @moscas this is really frustrating. I'm considering a switch to another IDE.